# Coverage not showing executed lines in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, code-coverage, virtualenv, nosetests

I have a project and I am trying to run nosetests with coverage. I am running in a virtualenv.
When I run

```
$ python setup.py nosetests
```

The tests run fine but coverage is not showing that any code is executed (coverage
is all 0%).

```
Name                                 Stmts   Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------
package.module1                         60      0     0%   3-106
package.module2                         32      0     0%   3-93
package.module3                         55      0     0%   8-74
package.module4                         38      0     0%   3-125
package.module5                        107      0     0%   8-123
package.module6                          1      0     0%   1
package.module7                         41      0     0%   3-143
package.module8                        150      0     0%   7-281
package.module9                        158      0     0%   3-338
------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                  642      0     0%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 15 tests in 0.099s
```

Coverage version 3.0b3, Darwin Kernel Version 9.7.0, Mac OS X 10.5.7, setuptools 0.6c9,
nose 0.11.1, Python 2.5.4

Answer (score 2):

This is going to require some back and forth.  How can I see your code?

And why did you come to stackoverflow for an answer rather than to the developer (that is, me)? :)

Answer (score 2):

try...

```
easy_install "coverage==2.85"
```

I was having the same issue and this solved my problem and gave me glorious coverage reports as expected.